# Prove that $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,5]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I have several doubts about this exercise because one of the conditions a function must have to be Riemann integrable is to be continuous in that interval, condition $\lfloor x\rfloor$ does not meet. How is this exercise done? Or what does the approach have to be?

Prove that $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is Riemann integrable on [0,5] and calculate $\int_0^5 \lfloor x\rfloor \,dx$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor = floor(x)$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you read that a Riemann integrable function needs to be continuous?

Comment: Yes, now I notice. If a function is continuous, then is Riemann integrable, but in this case, I don't know why is it integrable.

Comment: Piece-wise continuity is sufficient for Riemann integrability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monotone functions are integrable! To calculate the integral,  integrate over  [j,j+1] for j=0,1,2,3,4 and add.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try to prove (or find a prove in your textbook) that a function is Riemann integrable if it has only finitely many discontinuities in the interval of integration.

More generally, a function is Riemann integrable if it has countable many discontinuities. You might also want to try to find a prove for this.

Comment: More generally still, a function is Riemann integrable, if & only if the measure of its set of discontinuities is 0. The characteristic function of the Cantor set, for example, has uncountably many discontinuities - in particular, they lie at every point in the Cantor set - yet also has a well-defined Riemann integral of 0.

Comment: I didn't say 'if and only if'. There is no point in wanting to explain lesbesgue null sets to someone who had difficulties with integrating floor function.

Comment: Oh yes, of course; I never thought you did ;) it was just a side comment. I've always been fascinated by the occasional tantalizing "sneak preview" of surprising results and strange pathologies that lay just a little bit ahead of my current understanding level. They tend to spur my interest & motivate me to learn. My thought was just to *motivate* measure theory, rather than explain it, by drawing attention to the curious notion that a function must have a set of discontinuities that is, in a loose sense, "even worse than uncountable", before it ceases to be Riemann integrable in general.

Answer (score 1):

A bounded function on a compact interval [a, b] is Riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere (the set of its points of discontinuity has measure zero, in the sense of Lebesgue measure).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral